# ds_list can't handle more than 3 elements

Tags: c

i don't know why i can't even add 4th element...

(im working on windows with mingw)

this is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 100
typedef struct ds_list_element {
    char value[MAX];
    struct ds_list_element *next;
}* ds_list;
int ds_list_empty(ds_list id) { // id listy
    if (id == NULL) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
ds_list ds_list_add(ds_list id, char add[MAX]) {
    ds_list temp;
    temp = (ds_list)(malloc(sizeof(ds_list)));
    strcpy(temp->value,add);
    temp->next = id;
    return temp;
}
void ds_list_print(ds_list id) {
    if (ds_list_empty(id) == 0) {
        printf("%s\n",id->value);
        ds_list_print(id->next);
    }
}
int main () {
    ds_list my_list = NULL;
    my_list = ds_list_add(my_list,"one");
    my_list = ds_list_add(my_list,"two");
    my_list = ds_list_add(my_list,"three");
    my_list = ds_list_add(my_list,"four");
    ds_list_print(my_list);
    return 0;
}
```

and the result is:

```
four
three
two
 y
Press any key to continue . . .
```

i don't know why it is happening. everything should work fine.
my friend told me it is working on ubuntu...

Comment: That is why never typedef a pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
temp = (ds_list)(malloc(sizeof(ds_list)));
```

will be

```
temp = malloc(sizeof(*temp)));
```

You want to allocate memory for `struct ds_list_element` not `struct ds_list_element*`.  Don't hide pointers behind typedef name. It rarely helps.

Also you should check the return value of `malloc` and the casting is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ds_list` as structure not a pointer

```
typedef struct ds_list_element {
    char value[MAX];
    struct ds_list_element *next;
}ds_list;
```

and allocate memory for the structure not a pointer.

Working program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAX 100

typedef struct ds_list_element {
    char value[MAX];
    struct ds_list_element *next;
}ds_list;


int ds_list_empty(ds_list *id) { // id listy
    if (id == NULL) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

ds_list * ds_list_add(ds_list *id, char add[MAX]) {
    ds_list *temp;

    temp = (malloc(sizeof(ds_list)));
    strcpy(temp->value,add);
    temp->next = id;
    return temp;
}

void ds_list_print(ds_list *id) {

    if (ds_list_empty(id) == 0) {
        printf("%s\n",id->value);
        ds_list_print(id->next);
    }
}

int main () {
    ds_list *my_list = NULL;

    my_list = ds_list_add(my_list,"one");
    my_list = ds_list_add(my_list,"two");
    my_list = ds_list_add(my_list,"three");
    my_list = ds_list_add(my_list,"four");

    ds_list_print(my_list);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
four
three
two
one
```